# Problems getting an external file's info (status and size)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if there is a way to check if an external file is online, or available with AngularJS (or JavaScript). And if I could determine the size in some way (would be a plus). I first thought of using the head function of $http. But it turns out this doesn't always work, and I can't seem to find the size in the header information...

```
var file = { src: '//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js' };

$http.head(file.src)
    .success(function(data, status, headers) {
       file.size = headers(['content-length']); // always empty
       file.status = 'online'; 
    })
    .error(function() {
        file.status = 'offline';
    });
```

Anyone any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have come to the conclusion that there is no (reliable) way to do this with JavaScript at this point in time. I tried implementing a solution by injecting a script tag into an hidden iframe, and then check the result with the onload or onerror events. However when there is an error in the external file you are loading your code stops as well. So even this method is not viable.

So from this point I will search for the solution on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

The header you are looking for is [HTTP `content-length`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

```
$http.head(file.src)
  .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     file.size = headers(['content-length']);
     file.status = 'online';
  });
```

Of course, since you are running on the browser you'll only be able to perform the request to your server or to any server that specify the [CORS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simple_example) `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

For everything else, you'll have to proxy the requests through your own server. Do notice, however, that not all servers respond to `HEAD` requests - in which case you'll have to perform a full `GET` and either cancel the request after a timeout (file is online and downloading) or an error is thrown (file is offline).

Comment: I searched for this header and could not find it. Seems like this information is lost somewhere...

Comment: @Velter yes, you forgot to include the returning parameters in your callback. Edited the answer with the proper code.

Comment: No, I know the i forgot to returning parameters, was just a small example. What you wrote here i tried as well. But the header 'content-length' was always emtpy. The main problem here is not getting the size (would be nice), it's having a certain way to know the file is available, which is not the case for $http.head...